# Как задать полный размер 2D списка?(C#)

Tags: c#, list

Вот к примеру чтобы задать размер двухмерного массива пишем `int[,] array = new int[10, 2]`, а в случае с `List` мне удается задать размер только первого измерения: `List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>(10)`, а как задать размер всех списков второго измерения при инициализации?

Comment: list[0] = new List<int>(10)? Лист у вас всё равно пустой будет, вам так или иначе надо будет его заполнить 10-ю экземплярами List<int>

Comment: А нельзя этот процесс как нибудь упростить? Чтобы не писать по десять раз list[n] = new List<int>(10)

Comment: Ошибся, там нужно будет вызывать .Add, а не через индекс обращаться. Заполнить легко, циклом For, где условием будет i < list.Capacity, в теле вызываете у list.Add и туда кладете новый экземпляр List<int> туда

Comment: Наверное, через `Linq` проще сгенерить нужное число элементов и сделать `.ToList()`, но вообще не путайте `Capacity` и размер списка. При инициализации списка вы можете только задать *предполагаемый* размер, до которого планируете вырастить список. Это чтобы он не тратил время на перераспределение памяти при росте. А физический размер у него будет ноль всё-равно после инициализации с любым параметром `Capacity`.

Comment: Кроме двухмерных массивов `[,]` есть ещё jagged array (зубчатый или ступенчатый массив): `[][]`. Так вот `List<List<T>>` - это последний случай. И размеры второго измерения (и всех последующих) придётся задавать в явно цикле.